# opus_decode returning corrupted stream

Tags: c, curl, ogg, decoder, opus

I am decoding ogg opus data which is streaming live from icecast server. I am using libopus to decode.
Data gets decoded sometimes but most of the times op_decode() returns -4 which indicates corrupted stream. 
This is the callback function used to access data using curl library.

```
#define SAMPLE_RATE 48000
#define CHANNELS 2
#define MAX_FRAME_SIZE 6*960
size_t play_stream(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    FILE *fp;
    opus_int16 out[MAX_FRAME_SIZE * CHANNELS];
    int error;
    int i;
    unsigned char pcm_bytes[MAX_FRAME_SIZE * CHANNELS * 2];
    int frame_size;

    frame_size = opus_decode(decoder, (unsigned char*)buffer, (opus_int32)size * nmemb, out, MAX_FRAME_SIZE, 0);

    if (frame_size < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "decoder failed: %s\n", opus_strerror(frame_size));

    }


    return size * nmemb;
}
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: the most obvious thing to check is: is size*nmemb the correct size?

Comment: @user253751 size*nmemb is the size that is given by curl callback... It keeps on changing.

Comment: What does buffer contains? You should pass an raw opus packet for each opus_decode call. You should extrapolate it from ogg before decoding.

Answer (score 1):

The `opus_decode()` function decodes an Opus packet, not an Ogg Opus stream.  You could use the Ogg library to get the packets out of the stream and then libopus to decode the packets, but an easier way to is to use the [opusfile](https://opus-codec.org/release/dev/2018/09/18/opusfile-0_11.html) library.  Opusfile can even read the stream directly from the network.

Comment: Thanku, i am able to decode url directly using opusfile. But how can I close the streaming audio connection from network ?

Comment: @SajuAlexander: Just call op_free() on the OggOpusFile when you're done with it.